# maatwebsite/excel v2.1.0 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ~1.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to install maatwebsite/excel package on laravel 5.2, but I am getting this error when I run `composer require maatwebsite/excel 2.1`

> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.5
>       - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 2.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[v2.1.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/css-selector v3.0.7
>       - Installation request for tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (locked at 2.2.1) -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.1].
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/css-selector v3.0.7
>       - maatwebsite/excel v2.1.0 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ~1.5 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 
>   1.5.4, 1.5.5].
>       - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.0 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>       - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.1 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>       - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.2 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>       - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.3 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>       - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 1.5.4 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.0, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.1, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.10, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.11, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.12, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.13, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.14, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.15, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.16, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.17, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.18, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.19, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.2, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.20, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.21, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.22, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.23, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.24, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.25, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.26, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.27, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.28, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.29, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.3, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.30, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.31, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.32, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.33, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.34, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.35, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.36, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.37, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.38, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.39, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.4, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.40, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.41, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.42, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.43, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.44, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.45, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.46, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.47, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.48, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.49, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.5, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.50, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.6, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.7, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.8, v3.0.7].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/css-selector[v2.8.9, v3.0.7].
>       - Installation request for symfony/css-selector (locked at v3.0.7, 
>        required as 2.8.*|3.0.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v3.0.7].

Also please tell me if this is the appropriate version for my configuration I need.

 
**composer.json**

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.0"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I have never this long error ever while installing any package.
I also need some suggestion what's the appropriate version for me to install. 
This is the first time I am using this package.
I tried `composer require maatwebsite/excel` but it started updating every package in `require-dev` and gave me version 3 and my website doesn't work
I don't want to update any other package, I just need to install this package.

Comment: why do you have `"symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*", "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"` in your requires ?

Comment: I don't know, it's old project. May be it came with laravel.

Comment: @deeepdark no it doesn't come with laravel, try removing the version on both, the composer will select the right one that works with mattwebsite